# Changing quarterly dates to monthly dates

Tags: r, date

I am currently trying to subtract 2 month for every 1st, 4th, 7th, etc... month with the intention to end at month end.

I am currently trying to subtract 1 month for every 2nd, 5th, 8th, etc... month 
with the intention to end at month end.

And I do not want to subtract any months for every 3th, 6th, 9th etc...
What I currently have

```
month_df <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~V1, ~V2, ~V3,
    105, 20080331, -0.087372, 
    105,  20080331, -0.01609, 
    105,  20080331, -0.022895,
    105,  20080630, 0.083682,
    105,  20080630, 0.034749,
    105,  20080630, -0.11045,
    105,  20080930, -0.01594,
    105,  20080930, -0.02046,
    105,  20080930, -0.14796,
    )
```

What I want to achieve

```
month_df <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~V1, ~V2, ~V3,
    105, 20080131, -0.087372, 
    105,  20080229, -0.01609, 
    105,  20080331, -0.022895,
    105,  20080430, 0.083682,
    105,  20080530, 0.034749,
    105,  20080630, -0.11045,
    105,  20080731, -0.01594,
    105,  20080829, -0.02046,
    105,  20080930, -0.14796,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function `no2ym` which convert from the numeric date format in the question to yearmon class and another `ym2no` which converts back using the end of the month.

After using `no2ym`, since yearmon represents year/month by year + 0 for Jan, year + 1/12 for Feb and so on we can just subtract 2:0/12 from that.  Finally convert back using `ym2no`.

```
library(zoo)

no2ym <- function(x) as.yearmon(as.character(x), format = "%Y%m%d")
ym2no <- function(x) as.numeric(format(as.Date(x, frac = 1), "%Y%m%d"))

month_df %>%  mutate(V2 = ym2no(no2ym(V2) - 2:0/12))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
     V1       V2      V3
  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1   105 20080131 -0.0874
2   105 20080229 -0.0161
3   105 20080331 -0.0229
4   105 20080430  0.0837
5   105 20080531  0.0347
6   105 20080630 -0.110 
7   105 20080731 -0.0159
8   105 20080831 -0.0205
9   105 20080930 -0.148
```

Comment: Dear, sorry I am quite a beginner. How would the code change if I wanted to keep the  %Y%m%d date format? Since that is what I need in order to merge with my other data file.

Comment: I mean it currently gives me 20080131, 20080229, etcc. Instead I would like it to show 2008-01-31, which I thought lubridate might help with? Sorry for all the questions, I have just recently started to pick this up.

Comment: Change `ym2no` to `ym2no <- function(x) as.Date(x, frac = 1)` or to `ym2no <- function(x) format(as.Date(x, frac = 1))` depending on what it is you want.

Comment: Thankyou sir, u were very helpfull. I cannot give you an upvote yet, but thankyou.